# Legendre symbol - Find all primes such that $(7/p)=1$

Tags: number-theory

I've been thinking a lot about this problem, but couldn't come up with an answer.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: the value depends on $p\pmod 7$ and $p\pmod 4$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First deal with $p=2$. This is easy.

For odd $p$, I suggest Reciprocity. There are two cases.

(i) Let $p$ be of the form $4k+1$. Then $(7/p)=(p/7)$. For $a=1,2,\dots,6$, determine which of the $(a/7)$ are equal to $1$. This can be done simply by squaring $1$, $2$, and $3$ modulo $7$.

(ii) Let $p$ be of the form $4k+3$. Then $(7/p)=-(p/7)$. For $a=1,2,\dots,6$ determine which of the $(a/7)$ are equal to $-1$.

Your ultimate characterization for odd primes $p$ can be put in terms of the congruence class of $p$ modulo $28$.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, sorry for this request; I have a similar problem, but with $(3/p)$. In this case how I can proceed? I do not understand how you pick, for example in passage i), that particular form that leads to $(7/p)=(p/7)$